# Unable to convert String type Array into Json

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to convert Array output into Json but It returns me both output same.

**Array Code:**

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
System.out.println(myStringArray);
gson.toJson(myStringArray);
System.out.println("Json Output" + gson.toJson(myStringArray));
```

Output of Array :`[a,b,c]`
Output of Json : `["a,b,c"]`

Above is just example of my data output. In actual I am using dynamic string array and adding 3 values per array index separated by comma. So each array index has 3 values like `array[0]= ["value1,value2,value3"]`

Expected Output : `[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3" }]`

Comment: I wonder why you're trying an Array into Json? Why don't you define an Object?

Comment: @troy - For some another purpose , I want final output in json. That's why trying to get it.

Comment: So your data format is `String[] myArray = {"value1,value2,value3","value6,value7,value8"};` and you want to make that into `["value1","value2","value3","value6","value7","value8"]`? What part of this do you need help with?

Comment: @coladict - It seems what output I am getting is not in json format.

Comment: @Helping Hands, we know JSON objects are written in key/value pairs, and I know the array is the value, but what's the key?

Comment: @troy - I added expected output in question.

Comment: @Helping Hands, I don't think you can convert it into json directly, you can use an object or convert it into a map first.

Comment: @troy - Can you give solution then?

Comment: @Helping Hands I answered your question, have you seen it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution of using Map

```
 public String convertArraysIntoJson(List<String[]> myStringArrays){
    List<Map<String, String>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String[] myStringArray : myStringArrays){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++){
            map.put("Key"+(i+1), myStringArray[i]);
        }
        maps.add(map);
    }
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    return gson.toJson(myStringArray);;
}
```